# How to insert text into one textarea out of several with id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two textareas with different ids which both have wysiwyg buttons for text formatting. I can insert the formatting tags into the first textarea however when I try to insert tags into the second textarea, the tags are inserted into the first one. Obviously when I use the buttons assigned to their respective textarea I would like the format tags to be inserted in the appropriate textarea. In jQuery I try to store the id of the buttons to concatenated with '#textarea' to recreate the textarea id.

```
        <button class="B" id="11">B</button>
        <button class="I" id="11">I</button>
        <button class="U" id="11">U</button>
        <button class="S" id="11">S</button>
        <div id="textarea1" class="textareaWrapper">
            <textarea id="textarea11" class="textarea"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="B" id="22">B</button>
        <button class="I" id="22">I</button>
        <button class="U" id="22">U</button>
        <button class="S" id="22">S</button>
        <div id="textarea2" class="textareaWrapper">
            <textarea id="textarea22" class="textarea"></textarea>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('button.B').click(function () {
                    var id = $('button.B').attr('id');
                    $('#textarea' + id).val($('#textarea' + id).val() + id);
                })
                $('button.I').click(function () {
                    var id = $('button.I').attr('id');
                    $('#textarea' + id).val($('#textarea' + id).val() + "<i></i>");
                })
                $('button.U').click(function () {
                    var id = $('button.U').attr('id');
                    $('#textarea' + id).val($('#textarea' + id).val() + "<u></u>");
                })
                $('button.S').click(function () {
                    var id = $('button.S').attr('id');
                    $('#textarea' + id).val($('#textarea' + id).val() + "<s></s>");
                })
            })
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not use same ids for multiple controls.
My suggestion is to use dummy attribute e.g.'data-group', which can be used in JavaScript and browser simply ignores it. Like:

```
        <button class="B" data-group="1">B</button>
        <button class="I" data-group="1">I</button>
        <button class="U" data-group="1">U</button>
        <button class="S" data-group="1">S</button>
        <div id="textarea1" class="textareaWrapper">
            <textarea id="textarea11" class="textarea"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="B" data-group="2">B</button>
        <button class="I" data-group="2">I</button>
        <button class="U" data-group="2">U</button>
        <button class="S" data-group="2">S</button>
        <div id="textarea2" class="textareaWrapper">
            <textarea id="textarea22" class="textarea"></textarea>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('button.B').click(function () {
                    var grp = $('button.B').attr('data-group');
                    $('#textarea' + grp).val($('#textarea' + grp).val() + id);
                })
                $('button.I').click(function () {
                    var grp = $('button.I').attr('data-group');
                    $('#textarea' + grp).val($('#textarea' + grp).val() + "<i></i>");
                })
                $('button.U').click(function () {
                    var grp = $('button.U').attr('data-group');
                    $('#textarea' + grp).val($('#textarea' + grp).val() + "<u></u>");
                })
                $('button.S').click(function () {
                    var grp = $('button.S').attr('data-group');
                    $('#textarea' + grp).val($('#textarea' + grp).val() + "<s></s>");
                })
            })
        </script>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: It works. I will use your method to avoid using the same id values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that inside your click handler you're getting a ref to the first button's id.

try this: `$(this).attr('id');`

Like:

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
            $('button.B').click(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $('#textarea' + id).val($('#textarea' + id).val() + id);
            })
            $('button.I').click(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $('#textarea' + id).val($('#textarea' + id).val() + "<i></i>");
            })
            $('button.U').click(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $('#textarea' + id).val($('#textarea' + id).val() + "<u></u>");
            })
            $('button.S').click(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $('#textarea' + id).val($('#textarea' + id).val() + "<s></s>");
            })
        })
```

Comment: Thanks! It's actually `$(this).attr('id')` but it works.

Comment: @ChrisC is referring to the non-quoted variable... I think.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you retrieve your ids:

```
$('button.S').attr('id');
```

This will get the id of the first element passing the selector. Consider this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqax2dq2/).